# Protractor - The 'files' list in config file 'tsconfig.json' is empty. (18002)

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I want to implement e2e in my Angular `v5.x` project using **protractor.js**. But when I run the command

`ng e2e -s false`

I'm getting this error below can anyone tell me how do I fix this?

```
[15:58:11] E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
The 'files' list in config file 'tsconfig.json' is empty. (18002)
    at load (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:159:13)
    at service (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:285:32)
    at shouldIgnore (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:293:21)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:302:11)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:84:5
[15:58:11] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Here is my **tsconfig.json** (which is located inside `e2e` folder)-

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to this [issue](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/1824) on GitHub, I've figured out the solution. The problem is with `ts-node` version. My version was `1.2.x` and for `ng e2e -s false` to work it needs a `v5.0.1`.

Version `>v5.0.1` are also throwing the same error.

**NOTE:- I didn't update any other files or dependencies**

Thanks to **@ashish701ranjan** for the [solution](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/1824#issuecomment-402447633)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened in a typescript mono repo, after creating some new packages.

Deleting all `node_modules` and reinstalling dependencies did it.

Answer (score -1):

Using the "files" property. Hope it helps you.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "core.ts",
        "sys.ts",
        "types.ts",
        "scanner.ts",
        "parser.ts",
        "utilities.ts",
        "binder.ts",
        "checker.ts",
        "emitter.ts",
        "program.ts",
        "commandLineParser.ts",
        "tsc.ts",
        "diagnosticInformationMap.generated.ts"
    ]
}
```